# Google Maps Overlay Offset

Tags: google-maps, overlay, offset, geoserver

Following problem with Google Maps and overlays created by Geoserver: Depending on the zoom level and the latitude, there is a offset of the overlay to the north. The further north (Sweden vs. Spain) and zoomed-out (Level 3,4), the bigger the offset. On deeper zoom-levels (Google-Zoom levels > 5), there is no offset at all; that's why I assume code and data storage is correct.
What might be the problem? Any hint is appreciated, thank you!